# Get service in Rest Controller is not getting called

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
package test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController

public class CommodityControllerTest {

    @GetMapping("/api/test")
    public void test() {

        System.out.println("in controler");
    }
}
```

When I call Get service from POSTMAN, it's not getting called as there is nothing coming in the console.

What I am doing wrong here?

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Where exactly are you looing for the console output? What URL with what HTTP method do you call in Postman? Your question lacks some very important context information.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - I have added an image and more details. Please take a look.

Comment: Uhm ... Your image shows code that differs from the code snippet you provided earlier. More: The code image does not contain any console output statements. How can you get such an output? Additionally, you did not show what exactly you call in Postman. Was I so unclear in my questions? I am now voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `CommodityControllerTest` class to the `com.miapp.MIApp.controller` package.

Your `CommodityControllerTest` class probably isn't getting picked up during the component scan.

From your screen shot it looks like the class is not in a package. If you just have an `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on you main class you will need to put your class in a package below where your main class is so that it can find it.